# How to undo a JavaScript function? The first function works, but I want to undo it with the second function, but that one does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
    <script>
      const elem= document.getElementById("close");
```

The following function removes the `div` container like I wanted:

```
      window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("close").onclick = function(){
            this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
            .removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
            return false;
        };
    
      };
```

The following function should undo the effect of the first function automatically when the user scrolls back to the top, but it does not work.

```
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        document.getElementById('showScroll').innerHTML = window.pageYOffset;
        if (window.pageYOffset===0){
          document.getElementById("close")=elem;
          }
          return false;
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I don't think that the automatic scrolling from removing an element emits a "scroll" event, but I may be wrong

Comment: I have a div container on my webpage, which I made it to pop up while scrolling down. It also has button to close that div container. I am getting that container back while I refresh the page, but I want it to appear automatically, once I scroll to the top.

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML and also any error you see in your browsers dev tools inspect console.

Comment: `document.getElementById("close")=elem;` does not make any sense. What do you think that is doing?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is with this line:

`document.getElementById("close")=elem;`

It should be something like:

`document.getElementById("container").appendChild(elem);`

The problem is that the element with the `id` of `close` is no longer in the DOM (it was removed when the button was clicked) and so you cannot refer to it in the code once it has gone.

Therefore, you need to refer to its parent, for example `container`, and append the button `elem` as a child to the `container`. If `elem` is not at the end of the `container` then you have to work out where to append it.

However, there are also multiple `parentNodes` in the first code, which are probably not necessary.

Here is a detailed reference: [MDN Node.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

Here is a demonstration that shows you this working:

```js
const elem = document.getElementById("close");

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("close").onclick = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
  };
};

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  document.getElementById("showScroll").textContent = 'scrollY: ' + Math.floor(window.pageYOffset);
  if (window.pageYOffset === 0) {
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(elem);
  }
});
```

```css
#container {
  border: solid 3px red;
  padding: 10px;
}

#showScroll {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p id="showScroll">scrollY: 0</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <button id="close">
    Close
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### The fix

if you use this:

```js
this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
```

then its opposite is this:

```js
this.parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(element);
```

So to sum it up:

```js
// this will remove the element but keep it saved inside elem
let keep = this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
// this will place back the element you removed
this.parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(keep);
```

that is because`document.getElementById("close")` has already been removed.

### A better solution

A better solution to this if you are going to insert back the element anyways is to play with its css.
Just add `display:none` in its css and the element will be the same as gone (without actually getting deleted).

```js
// hide the element without deleting it
document.getElementById("close").style.display = "none";
// make the element visible again
document.getElementById("close").style.display = "block";
```